# when I start Android studio I get this Error:(21, 76) error: cannot find symbol variable fab

Tags: android, android-studio

Im just newbie, and im starting with tutorials. I installed `Android studio 1.4` and I get this error message when it starts:

```
Error:(21, 76) error: cannot find symbol variable fab
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I'm running Windows 10, as I already said I'm using Android studio 1.4
Does anybody have a clue what could be the issue?
I've tried to search the web and forums but so far I didn't find anything helpful.

Thank You so much.

Comment: is this after compiling a project or just after installing android studio?

Comment: just after instaling it and starting it.

Answer (score 5):

In resent version for android studio the black activity starts with a little mail icon. This icon is coded as a floating action button (fab). You are probably getting that error after deleting the mail icon by mouse on the design view.
Make sure the corresponding XML and Java is updated by deleting.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

from main.xml
and

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
```

from the MainActivity.java

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that you use JDK7 (or later) and this JDK defined in java_home environment variable.

Also add the following Gradle dependency for Fab Button:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Comment: Im using JDK7.0.79 because when I used on my last lap top JDK8... i had problem with eclipse. and I allredy added JAVA_HOME enviiroment variable.